# Embedding SVG shapes in a d3.js animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js

I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aucontraire/tT84p/). There are a couple of things I need to do.

1. How do you properly embed svg code (from an existing shape) into a d3.js animation? My svg is popping up twice.
2. How do you attach that svg to another shape so that the animation happens simultaneously for both shapes?

   #slider {
           width: 490px;
       }
       #_rb {
           color: #000;
       }
      

       
           5

JavaScript:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    minRadius = 10,
    maxRadius = 250,
    minHeight = 100,
    maxWidth = 500;

var duration = 5000;

d3.select("body").append("input")
    .attr("type", "range")
    .attr("id", "slider")
    .attr("min", 1000)
    .attr("max", 10000)
    .attr("value", duration)
    .on("change", function () {
    duration = this.value;
    d3.select("#_rb").property("value", d3.round(duration / 1000));
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", width / 2)
    .attr("cy", height / 2)
    .attr("r", minRadius)
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .call(transition, minRadius, maxRadius);

svg.append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#Layer_1")
    .attr("width", width / 2)
    .attr("height", height / 2)
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .call(transition, minHeight, maxWidth);

function transition(element, start, end) {
    element.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("r", end)
        .attr("height", end)
        .attr("width", end)
        .each("end", function () {
        d3.select(this).call(transition, end, start);
    });
}
```

Comment: To clarify:  The animation part is what you want, but you don't want the static star just taking up space at the top?

Comment: If so, the easiest solution with your existing code is to just set the hard-coded SVG to have zero height and width: http://jsfiddle.net/tT84p/1/ .  You can't use "display:none;" because that would be inherited by the `<use>` element.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I would keep the star inside the circle?

Comment: You would need to transition the position of the embedded SVG, not just it's height and width.

Comment: How do I get a shape to transform from the middle instead of growing as it slides diagonally? You should make your comments an answer so that I can accept it. http://jsfiddle.net/aucontraire/d4uQy/1/